# Iterating over PyoDBC result without fetchall()

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I'm trying to process a very large query with pyodbc and I need to iterate over the rows without loading them all at once with fetchall().

Is there a good and principled way to do this?

Comment: I think you can also do `for row in cursor:`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure - use a `while` loop with `fetchone`.

http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchone

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    # do something
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

*edit* In fact, doing it using the cursor directly as an iterator as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59738011/2337736 is more idiomatic.

Comment: I would prefer to not repeat the fetchone line.  You can do while True: row = cursor.fetchOne(); if row is None: break; # do something

Comment: Use `for row in cursor:` loop, as advised by @Daniel

Answer (score 12):

According to [official documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started) the cursor is apparently an iterator. Therefore, you shouldn't need to create a custom iterator/generator.

> If you are going to process the rows one at a time, you can use the cursor itself as an iterator:

```
cursor.execute("select user_id, user_name from users"):
for row in cursor:
    print(row.user_id, row.user_name)
```

Answer (score 8):

you could also use `cursor.fetchmany()` if you want to batch up the fetches (defaults to 1 if you don't override it)

http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchmany