# Export 2Gb+ SELECT to CSV with Python (out of Memory)

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, netezza

I'm trying to export a large file from Netezza (using Netezza ODBC + pyodbc), this solution throws memoryError, If I loop without "list" it's VERY slow. do you have any idea of a intermediate solution that doesn't kill my server/python process but can run faster?

```
cursorNZ.execute(sql)
archi = open("c:\test.csv", "w")
lista = list(cursorNZ.fetchall())
for fila  in lista:
    registro = ''
    for campo in fila:
        campo = str(campo)
        registro = registro+str(campo)+";"
    registro = registro[:-1]
    registro = registro.replace('None','NULL')
    registro = registro.replace("'NULL'","NULL")
    archi.write(registro+"\n")
```

---- Edit ----

Thank you, I'm trying this:
Where "sql" is the query,
cursorNZ is

```
connMy = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=.....)
cursorNZ = connNZ.cursor()

chunk = 10 ** 5  # tweak this
chunks = pandas.read_sql(sql, cursorNZ, chunksize=chunk)
with open('C:/test.csv', 'a') as output:
    for n, df in enumerate(chunks):
        write_header = n == 0
        df.to_csv(output, sep=';', header=write_header, na_rep='NULL')
```

Have this:
**AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'**
Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707264/iterating-over-pyodbc-result-without-fetchall especially the reference to [fetchmany](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchmany).

Comment: pass `read_sql` your connection instead. I'll edit my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `cursorNZ.fetchall()`.

Instead, loop through the cursor directly:

```
with open("c:/test.csv", "w") as archi:  # note the fixed '/'
    cursorNZ.execute(sql)
    for fila in cursorNZ:
        registro = ''
        for campo in fila:
            campo = str(campo)
            registro = registro+str(campo)+";"
        registro = registro[:-1]
        registro = registro.replace('None','NULL')
        registro = registro.replace("'NULL'","NULL")
        archi.write(registro+"\n")
```

Personally, I would just use pandas:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas

cnn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=.....)
chunksize = 10 ** 5  # tweak this
chunks = pandas.read_sql(sql, cnn, chunksize=chunksize)

with open('C:/test.csv', 'a') as output:
    for n, df in enumerate(chunks):
        write_header = n == 0
        df.to_csv(output, sep=';', header=write_header, na_rep='NULL')
```

Comment: The `pandas` solution would have a large memory footprint.

Comment: @tdelaney `read_sql` can take a `chunksize` argument that could help manage that.

Comment: But you still have a 2gb+ dataframe in memory. There is a speed advantage to doing it in `pandas` of course so maybe some outer loop that builds smaller frames.

Comment: @tdelaney I think the latest edit addresses your concerns too

Comment: It works and it's MUCH faster than the windows client for exporting data.
There is an error here:

**chunksize** = 10 ** 5
and the use of the variable in next line (I used "chunk" in both)


Thank you!